# SAP BW Incomplete data on reports after data loading

Tags: sap-bw

I'm a beginner in `SAP` BW and I have a problem with my SAP instance. Some of the data disappears on reports after loading.

My report uses the source table /BIC/TABX.
Loading data into this table looks like (delta loading):
data from several sources are loaded into the table:

1. ODSO Y1 -> my report ODSO X (/BIC/TABX) (after filtering data from ODSO X)
2. RSDS Y2 -> my report ODSO X (/BIC/TABX) from flat xls files

In the morning, data was manually loaded. There were 100,000+ records in the target table / BIC / TABX after loading.
There was probably another load during the night (possibly by job) and the number of records after that load has decreased to 4499.
Anyone have any idea what could be causing the data reduction?
I would like to add that after the first charge where there were 100,000 + records,   I missed the data from the current month, after overnight loading, some part of the data for the previous months are missing, while for the current month there are many more data.

Comment: looks like data corruption. I am not very familiar with BW, but it seems there is some consistency checker which works by schedule which removes broken entries in the evening that you saw in the morning before its run. First of all, check table logs for /BIC/TABX both on BW and on database level.

Comment: `/BIC/TABX` is a master table, and master data has built-in deduplication, i.e. it cannot have duplicated entries, they are overwritten by default. Maybe someone does an delta update/delete after you by the same key and purges your data? Just an assumption

Comment: Little correction, Data to my  DSO Y are transfered from two sources: 1. Other DSO X, 2. Flat file.  I noticed that some data from DSO X aren't updated - they are overwritten with blank data, so  some records on DSO Y have correct data from flat file and blank data from DSO X. On DSO X are correct data from flat file, I don't know what goes wrong with transfer from DSO X to Y. There is a problem only with updated records.  Any suggestions ?